# reports using ssrs from JIRA

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, jira

I am looking for way to build reports using SSRS from JIRA if that is not possible I am okay moving the data from Jira to a SQL DB utilizing SSIS. I am new to Jira and REST API.  Connecting directly to the Jira back end Database is not an option

Comment: So what's your question?  Extract the data using SSIS and build the report off the data's new location.

Comment: What data are you trying to extract from Jira?

Comment: I am looking to extract issues from Jira to enhance the available reporting

Answer (score 0):

The jira api currently only supports JSON. so your best bet is to either build a custom reporting services extension to handle JSON as a data source or create a webservice that passes through the json calls and converts the results to xml which SSRS will be able to handle.

while both of these sound difficult depending on your requirements may only take a few lines of C# code:

there also seem to be a few 3rd party options but I haven't tried them

Comment: Do you happen to have sample code I don't think third party would work for me I will need to build something internally